# программа не выводит результат

Tags: python, python-3.x

имеется такой скрипт написанный на питоне:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
   global nick
   os.system ('clear')
   nick = input(Fore.CYAN + Style.BRIGHT + 'Введите ник: ')
   return nick
def vk():
   response = requests.get('https://vk.com/' + nick)
   x = (response.status_code)
   if x == '200':
       print (Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT + '[VK]-Удачно! https://vk.com/' + nick)
   elif x == '503':
       print (Fore.RED + style.BRIGHT + '[VK]-Сервер не отвечает. Код ошибки 503')
   elif x == '500':
       print (Fore.RED + style.BRIGHT + '[VK]-Сервер не отвечает. Код ошибки 500')
   elif x == '404':
       print (Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + '[VK]-Ничего не найдено!')
def ok():
   response = requests.get('https://ok.ru/' + nick)
   x = (response.status_code)
   if x == '404':
       print (Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + '[OK]-Ничего не найдено!')
   elif x == '503':
       print (Fore.RED + style.BRIGHT + '[OK]-Сервер не отвечает. Код ошибки 503')
   elif x == '500':
       print (Fore.RED + style.BRIGHT + '[OK]-Сервер не отвечает. Код ошибки 500')
   elif x == '200':
       print (Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT + '[OK]-Удачно! https://ok.ru/' + nick)
   

main()
vk()
ok()
```

Когда ввожу ник ,программа не выводит ничего, но если вывести переменную x на экран ,то код выводиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.status_code` - это не строка, а число. Сравнивайте с числами и всё будет работать.

```
if x == 200:
...
```